# Complex Domain and Sub Domain

Tags: php, ajax, dns, cross-domain, subdomain

I am new on stackoverflow and requires a quick assistance on an issue i been facing from past few days. I tried to search for the solution by googling it but didnt found anything. Maybe because i am not searching it right.

So my issue is, Suppose i have a subdomain lets just say sub1.domain1.com and all the scripts and files are on this subdomain. Now i have another domain let say domain2.com 
I want to operate all the scripts on the subdomain from the another domain and also the address bar should display that its been running from the domain2.com but not on the sub1.domain1.com.

Is this possible and if yes then how. I am working on LAMP Platform powered by PHP-MYSQL-AJAX-JSON-XML

Please Help!!
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: If you're running Virtual Hosts on Apache, use a [`ServerAlias` in the `VirtualHost` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias). e.g. `ServerName sub1.domain1.com` and `ServerAlias domain2.com`

Comment: No i am not using virtual host

Comment: ok, so you're using IP-based single hostname serving. the only way i can see this working is on the DNS layer: use a `CNAME` record to point to the primary domain: `domain2.com. IN CNAME sub1.domain1.com.` apache won't know the difference since it is serving up the page from the IP layer and not the hostname/HTTP layer.

Comment: And this can be redone for say domain3.com->sub2.domain1.com

Comment: sure! `domain3.com. IN CNAME sub2.domain1.com.` - don't forget the `.` at the end :)

Comment: @zamnuts In which DNS layer i should create a CNAME record. I mean i tried to edit it in the cPanel of domain1.com

Comment: cPanel! why didn't you say so. you are in fact using VirtualHosts. anyways, you shouldn't have to edit any configs by hand: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/domain-alias-75491.html Just add a parked domain for the primary domain name (sub1.domain1.com i'm assuming?) parked domains can even be subdomains i think... anyways, just make sure you point the NS of domain2.com and domain3.com to the same nameservers that sub1.domain1.com uses (which should be something like ns1.sub1.domain1.com and ns2.sub1.domain1.com (just a hunch))

Comment: @zamnuts I cant able to create a park domain as i do not 0/0 of parked domain

Comment: if you have access to WHM, increase your parked domain limit, if not, you gotta go back to editing the DNS zone for sub1.domain1.com, simply add a new line in the DNS config per my previous instruction.